# Angular.js: Adding a simple route to a demo app?

Tags: angularjs

I am building a really simple demo Angular application, to see how it compares to Backbone, and I've got stuck when it comes to routing, although I've read the [routing tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07).

I'd like the route in my demo app to update whenever the `<select>` element changes, to `/LHR` or `/SFO` or whatever the new value of the select is (and presumably `/#LHR` etc in browsers without the History API).

I'd also like the router to handle the initial path when the page loads, and set up the default value of the `<select>` option.

Here is my HTML - I only have one template:

```
<html ng-app="angularApp">
[...]
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<select ng-model="airport" ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in airportOptions" ng-change='newAirport(airport)'></select>
<p>Current value: {{airport}}</p>
</body></html>
```

And here is my JS in full:

```
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/:airportID', {templateUrl: 'angular.html', controller: AppCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
angularApp.controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

  $scope.airportOptions = [
      { name: 'London Heathrow', value: 'LHR' }, 
      { name: 'San Francisco International', value: 'SFO' }, 
      { name: 'Paris Charles de Gaulle', value: 'CDG' }
  ];

  $scope.airport = $scope.airportOptions[0].value; // Or the route if provided

  $scope.newAirport = function(newAirport) {
       console.log('newAirport', newAirport);
  };

});
```

I'm not at all sure that I've set up the route provider correctly, and currently it's giving me `Uncaught ReferenceError: AppCtrl is not defined from angularApp`. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I fixed the ReferenceError by putting AppCtrl in quotes, thanks commenter. Now my problem is that `$routeParams` is empty when I try to navigate to `/#LHR`. How can I get the route parameter?

UPDATE 2: Got the route working - feels a bit hacky though. Am I doing it right?

```
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', []);
angularApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/:airportID', {templateUrl: 'angular.html', controller: "AppCtrl"}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});


angularApp.controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl ($scope, $routeParams, $location) {

  $scope.airportOptions = [
      { name: 'London Heathrow', value: 'LHR' }, 
      { name: 'San Francisco International', value: 'SFO' }, 
      { name: 'Paris Charles de Gaulle', value: 'CDG' }
  ];

  var starting_scope = null;
  ($location.path()) ? starting_scope = $location.path().substr(1) : starting_scope = $scope.airportOptions[0].value;
  $scope.airport = starting_scope;

  $scope.newLeague = function(newLeague) {
       $location.path("/" + newLeague);
  }
```

Comment: In this line when('/:airportID', {templateUrl: 'angular.html', controller: AppCtrl}) try to give the controller name in quotes, like 'AppCtrl'

Comment: That fixes the issue, thanks! Now I just need to work out how to get the route parameters...